# Dynamically adapt a text to a path element in an SVG

Tags: svg, path, font-size, viewbox

My SVG has shapes with different dimensions as below, and I would like my text to have a size adapted to the length of its associated shape (fill without overflow).

I tried *font-size-adjust* but no result and *textLength lengthAdjust* deforms my text, should i use textPath & href logic ?

Thank you for your help

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 220 220">

  <g>
  <path fill="orange" d="M30 110 L 20 110 L 20 20 L 30 10 L 40 20 L 40 110 Z"/>
    <text font-size="1em" transform="rotate(-90, 30, 110)" x="30" y="110" dominant-baseline="middle">Object number 1</text>
  </g>
  
  <g>
  <path fill="red" d="M 50 110 L 40 110 L 40 50 L 50 40 L 60 50 L 60 110 Z"/>
  <text transform="rotate(-90, 50, 110)" x="50" y="110" dominant-baseline="middle">Object number 2</text>
  </g>
  
  <g>
  <path fill="yellow" d="M 80 110 L 60 110 L 60 50 L 80 40 L 100 50 L 100 110 Z"/>
  <text transform="rotate(-90, 80, 110)" x="80" y="110" dominant-baseline="middle">Object number 3</text>
  </g>
  
</svg>
```

This is the rendering I would like to obtain:
[image: This is the rendering I would like to obtain:]

The space between letters is why i don't want to use textLength :

[image: This is why i don't want to use textLength]

My render here would be:

[image: good render]

Comment: You want to change the font size of text according ro shape, or chahge the shape's height according to the text? (The second option seems to be more relevant)

Comment: Hi @michaelRovinsky , I would like to change the font size of my text according to shape length, I edited my post with a picture of the desired rendering. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I see. There is another point: If the font size is large and the width is to narrow to contain the text, do you want to adjust the width of the path as well? And why in the first place the width of yellow path is different from those of orange and red ones?

Comment: These are shape of houses, with different dimensions extracted from database, so that's why they don't have the same length and width, and the names must fit in the house, not the house which must fit the text... In terms of width, the text shouldn't be too wide either,But I haven't thought about it yet. 

But yes if we want to go further, which I want to do:

**Make the text size fill the shape as much as possible in length without sticking out (in length or width)**

Hope this is clear, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

First method: tou can set the textLength of the text to be equal to the height of the path. Since your path has a tip I've opted for the 90% of the height. However if your path is much smaller than the text the text will apear crammed. To understand what I mean change the font-size to 3em

```js
let pthHeight = pth.getBBox().height;

txt.setAttribute("textLength",pthHeight*.9 )
```

```css
svg{width:50vh}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 120">
  <path fill="orange" id="pth" d="M30 110 L 20 110 L 20 20 L 30 10 L 40 20 L 40 110 Z"/>
    <text  id="txt" font-size="1em" transform="rotate(-90, 30, 110)" x="30" y="110" dominant-baseline="middle" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">Object number 1</text>  
</svg>
```

yet another solution would be changing the font size in a while loop till the text length is smaller than the height of the path. This assumes that the initial length of the text is longet than the height.

```js
let pthHeight = pth.getBBox().height;

function setFontSize(txt){
  let fs = txt.getAttribute("font-size");
  let textLength = txt.getComputedTextLength();
  let fontSize = txt.getAttribute("font-size");
  while(textLength > pthHeight){
    fontSize -= 1;
    txt.setAttribute("font-size",fontSize);
    textLength = txt.getComputedTextLength();
  }
}


setFontSize(txt)
```

```css
svg{width:50vh}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 120">
  <path fill="orange" id="pth"  d="M30 110 L 20 110 L 20 20 L 30 10 L 40 20 L 40 110 Z"/>
    <text id="txt" font-size="16" transform="rotate(-90, 30, 110)" x="30" y="110" dominant-baseline="middle" >Object number 1</text>  
</svg>
```

Comment: The width should be checked as well (see the last comment by @PeiKobayashi): `while(textLength > pthHeight || textWidth > pthWidth)`

Comment: Interesting ! 

But in the first case, the text is stretched or will be crammed just like you say but i want to modify the full font-size (example bellow)

[link](https://imgur.com/a/u0cBF48) 

The second method should be more appropriated but i can't call this function for all my elements (it's a huge SVG with many houses...)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the new image. As for the many houses you can loop the groups containing each a path and the text